# i want get data in form of dictionary from github but facing issue "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"

Tags: python, git, dictionary

iam working on getting no of commits from a repository in form of dictionary while i run the code iam getting error
"dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"

```
def branches_of_repo(repo, owner, api):
    branches = []
    next = True
    i = 1
    while next == True:
        url = api + '/repos/{}/{}/branches?page={}&per_page=100'.format(owner, repo, i)
        branch_pg = gh_session.get(url = url)
        branch_pg_list = [dict(item, **{'repo_name':'{}'.format(repo)}) for item in branch_pg.json()]    
        branch_pg_list = [dict(item, **{'owner':'{}'.format(owner)}) for item in branch_pg_list]
        branches = branches + branch_pg_list
        if 'Link' in branch_pg.headers:
            if 'rel="next"' not in branch_pg.headers['Link']:
                next = False
        i = i + 1
    return branches

branches = json_normalize(branches_of_repo('taniarascia', 'takenote', github_api))
```

and i face the below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-11cbe96472f5> in <module>
----> 1 branches = json_normalize(branches_of_repo('taniarascia', 'takenote', github_api))

<ipython-input-18-33fa60f7c673> in branches_of_repo(repo, owner, api)
      6         url = api + '/repos/{}/{}/branches?page={}&per_page=100'.format(owner, repo, i)
      7         branch_pg = gh_session.get(url = url)
----> 8         branch_pg_list = [dict(item, **{'repo_name':'{}'.format(repo)}) for item in branch_pg.json()]
      9         branch_pg_list = [dict(item, **{'owner':'{}'.format(owner)}) for item in branch_pg_list]
     10         branches = branches + branch_pg_list

<ipython-input-18-33fa60f7c673> in <listcomp>(.0)
      6         url = api + '/repos/{}/{}/branches?page={}&per_page=100'.format(owner, repo, i)
      7         branch_pg = gh_session.get(url = url)
----> 8         branch_pg_list = [dict(item, **{'repo_name':'{}'.format(repo)}) for item in branch_pg.json()]
      9         branch_pg_list = [dict(item, **{'owner':'{}'.format(owner)}) for item in branch_pg_list]
     10         branches = branches + branch_pg_list

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: I would check on what the output of branch_pg.json() and make sure the comprehension list comprehension you have works. Also you should be able to do `**{'repo_name':'{}'.format(repo), 'owner':'{}'.format(owner)}` instead of having that in two lines

Comment: but **{'repo_name':'{}'.format(repo), 'owner':'{}'.format(owner)} are different